# How to pass variable in url to Django List View

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a Django generic List View that I want to filter based on the value entered into the URL. 
For example, when someone enters mysite.com/defaults/41 I want the view to filter all of the values matching 41.
I have come accross a few ways of doing this with function based views, but not class based Django views.

I have tried:

**views.py**

```
class DefaultsListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = models.DefaultDMLSProcessParams
    template_name = 'defaults_list.html'
    login_url = 'login'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.DefaultDMLSProcessParams.objects.filter(device=self.kwargs[device])
```

**urls.py**

```
path('<int:device>', DefaultsListView.as_view(), name='Default_Listview'),
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are close, the `self.kwargs` is a dictionary that maps *strings* to the corresponding value extracted from the URL, so you need to use a string that contains `'device'` here:

```
class DefaultsListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = models.DefaultDMLSProcessParams
    template_name = 'defaults_list.html'
    login_url = 'login'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.DefaultDMLSProcessParams.objects.filter(
            device_id=self.kwargs['device']
        )
```

It is probably better to use `devide_id` here, since then it is *syntactically* clear that we compare identifiers with identifiers.

It might also be more "idiomatic" to make a `super()` call, such that if you later add mixins, these can "pre-process" the `get_queryset` call:

```
class DefaultsListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = models.DefaultDMLSProcessParams
    template_name = 'defaults_list.html'
    login_url = 'login'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(DefaultsListView, self).get_queryset().filter(
            device_id=self.kwargs['device']
        )
```