# How do I pass a variable in the URL to a Django list view?

Tags: python, django

First things first, I want to state I have seen the post created [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52871149/how-to-pass-variable-in-url-to-django-list-view). The problem is that I am still very new to the Django framework and every attempt I had at implementing this strategy into my code failed. Anyways, I was curious about how I could pass a string value from the URL into my listview. In my case, the variable named item so I can do a filtered query.  This was extremely easy to do on function-based views, but I am struggling to do the same on these class-based views. Thanks!

Class Based View:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    
    model = Post.objects.get(subject_name=item)
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5
```

Routing:

```
path('<str:item>/', PostListView.as_view(), name='post-view')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add get method to your PostListView:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    item = kwargs[“item”]
    // use the item variable here
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Same thing if you need to correct your context:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    data['item'] = kwargs['item']
    return data
```

Comment: Wait do you know how would I go about passing the item variable as context in the template?